# When to save document

Tags: android, save, android-activity

I'm making a simple app where I have an activity where the user can edit a document. I do not want to include a specific save button.

Where should  I save the document? I looked at the documentation but having never developed for android I found it a bit confusing: should I be using `onUserLeaveHint`? Or something else?

Basically, I'm looking for a function to override that would get called every time it's appropriate to save the document, i.e. when the user finishes editing it and thus the activity is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably override your Activity's `onPause()` method and save there.  That way any time the user leaves the Activity for any reason whatsoever, it will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

You should really provide a save button because:

1. You can validate input and show error messages to the user (better, when possible, to provide real-time checking as the user types, and showing an error message along with visually disabling the save button)
2. You can trigger actions in response to successful saving (updating thumbs, previews, databases)
3. **Users expect it**. I know this may sound silly, but everybody is used to the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons. If you don't provide them, the user will look around before finally pressing the back button, still unsure if he really saved the content or not. This is the most important point (As an example, the "Note" app in WP7 doesn't provide a save button and the note is saved just by hitting the back key: I never found this behavior consistent nor comfortable, and I never got used to it)

Otherwise the specific hook depends on your implementation details (it may even not exist one). If you just use Activity, simply override `onPause()`, which is guaranteed to be called everytime the Activity leaves the foreground. If you use Fragments, still override `onPause()`. If you use a custom mechanism to only switch widgets, then you have to hook into your system.

Comment: I would argue that in mobile apps, the saving is taken to be implied nowadays. Especially for small stuff like notes and my app, but thanks for the note.